# How to read a decimal value of order 0.000e-6 from a SqlDataReader in C# double variable

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I am trying to read some decimal values from my DB. These values are the order of 10<sup>-6</sup>. I am trying to read it into a `double` variable in C# using code like this: sqltype in database is "float". sample value to be read is "1.99999999495049E-06" –

```
Double [] rmseValues = null;

while (dataReader.Read())
{
    // This shows my datatype is float (sql)
    string temp = dataReader.GetDataTypeName(0);

    // This returns a value of "0"
    string temp1 = dataReader.GetOrdinal("RmseAll").ToString();

    // This throws exception of invalid typecast
    rmseValues[0] = dataReader.GetFloat(0);
}
```

Comment: How are planning on putting a fraction in an integer?

Comment: Sorry, for mistake, i am reading in a "double" variable

Comment: @AnujDubey I suspect you should actually be using a `decimal` here... what is the sql type in the database, and what does the value represent?

Comment: If you are actually reading in a double, then: `GetDouble`

Comment: @MarcGravell sqltype in database is "float". sample value to be read is "1.99999999495049E-06"

Comment: @AnujDubey: you should correct your question so the information in it is correct (ie update long to double, perhaps even showing the declaration of `rmseValues` so there is no doubt. At the moment there is a strange thing where the answers are answering what you've put in comments and so don't actually match the question itself!

Comment: @Chris Thanks . modified question

Comment: @AnujDubey `Double [] rmseValues = null;` .... um... where are you going to *put* these values, if that stays `null` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `GetDouble(0)` instead of `GetFloat(0)`

I think you will also need to edit that line :

```
Double [] rmseValues = null;
```

In fact your are trying to put values inside a null object as solution you need to initialize your `rmseValues`  array or just use a `List` of double

```
Double[] rmseValues = new Double[10];
```

Comment: that throws an exception "{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}"

Comment: That is a different problem, you need to show the code in this case.

Comment: @AnujDubey if `rmseValues[0] = dataReader.GetFloat(0);` throws a typecase exception, and `rmseValues[0] = dataReader.GetDouble(0);` throws a null-reference exception, then: `rmseValues` is `null` - so go fix that

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I'm guessing `Double [] rmseValues = null;` isn't helping ;p

Comment: Still had the old copy of the question on my screen, that explains it.

Comment: thanks ..initialization was messed up...Double[] rmseValues = new Double[10]; solved it

Comment: Ok you' r welcome bro. As I said it will be better if you use a list in case you don't know your array size . I will be grateful if you mark my answer as solution

Answer (score 0):

Use `GetInt64(0)` instead of `GetFloat(0)`

Comment: That wouldn't help store a value like the one cited

Answer (score 0):

In order not be dependent on RDBMS actual *background type* (say, `NUMBER(10, 3)` or alike) and its representation as .Net Type (e.g. `Single`) do a *conversion*:

```
  // rmseValues[0] should be Double
  rmseValues[0] = Convert.ToDouble(dataReader.GetValue(0));
```